# select the locator for passing values

Tags: selenium, testing, protractor

This is the code :

```
 <input _ngcontent-ljn-94="" accept-user-input="true" 
    autocomplete="off" 
    class="form-control autocompleteInput ng-touched ng-dirty ng-invalid" 
    display-property-name="name" formcontrolname="cityId" min-chars="2" 
    ng2-auto-complete="" path-to-data="payload.data" placeholder="Select 
    city *" value-property-name="id">
```

I have to use sendkeys to pass value in my autocomplete city field.I tried almost various ways to pass the value by using css,xpath ,but nothing is working.Sometimes it is showing "not able to focus on element" kinds of error.Someone can please provide me the solution.

Comment: It would help if we saw some instances of xpaths you wrote. The easiest route would be to add an id to the input element and then use the id select.